# How can I save an image to the camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, camera

I am new to Xcode (using 4.3) and am not sure how to save an image to the device's camera roll.  All that I have done so far is set up an IBAction for the button to save the image. What library method or function can I use to save an image to the user's camera roll?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

You use the [`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW29) function.

```
//Let's say the image you want to save is in a UIImage called "imageToBeSaved"
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToBeSaved, nil, nil, nil);
```

Edit:

```
//ViewController.m
- (IBAction)onClickSavePhoto:(id)sender{

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToBeSaved, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: Let's say I have '- (IBAction)onClickSavePhoto:(id)sender;' in my ViewController.h file, using what you have above, what exactly would I need to place in the ViewController.m file? Thanks again so much!

Comment: @user1470914 See my edit. Also, where are you getting the image to be saved to the camera roll? Is it already in your app's bundle, or does the user take a picture and then you save it to the camera roll?

Comment: Thanks for your patience qegal.  I haven't had a chance to revisit this issue until now.  Your EDIT us super helpful.  The image is in the app's bundle.  There are several images in the app and they can be viewed as small thumbnails. When a small thumbnail is selected it goes to a new view and a fullscreen version can be viewed. I have a button in the right corner of the top nav that says "save" and this is the button that I wish to save the image to the device's cameral roll so that it may be applied as a wallpaper. Thanks again for your help and patience (not sure why casperOne closed this).

Comment: I also added `UIImageView *imageToBeSaved;` to my .h file. I thought that I would have to add `@synthesize imageToBeSaved` in my .m but I get an error that says "missing context for property implementation declaration"

Comment: @user1470914 In the header file, did you only add `imageToBeSaved` as an instance variable or did you declare it as a property `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *imageToBeSaved`? Also, you save a `UIImage`, not a `UIImageView`. If you want to save the image displayed in a UIImageView, you can do this:    `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([imageView image], nil, nil, nil);`

Comment: Thank you for your patience, promptness and kindness. I did not declare @property. I followed your advice and this cleared my errors. The code compiles fine but the image does not show up in the simulators photos so I'll try it on a device tomorrow evening.  I only have a small window of time to code at night usually. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help. I just posted my question in a clearer manner with the current code here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166813/xcode-ios-save-image-to-cameral-roll-not-saving)so that it is easier to read as even though the code compiles I really cannot seem to get it to actually save to the phone's photo library. Thanks again so much! I appreciate your time.

Comment: I know it's old question but I want to save image with custom name. Will it possible to do this?

Comment: From iOS10 on, using NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key in plist is mandatory. Otherwhise the app crashes.

Answer (score 63):

Here's an answer for iOS8+ using the Photos framework.

**Objective-C:**

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>

UIImage *snapshot = self.myImageView.image;

[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    PHAssetChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:snapshot];
    changeRequest.creationDate          = [NSDate date];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"successfully saved");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error saving to photos: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

**Swift:**

```
// Swift 4.0
import Photos

let snapshot: UIImage = someImage

PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: snapshot)
}, completionHandler: { success, error in
    if success {
        // Saved successfully!
    }
    else if let error = error {
        // Save photo failed with error
    }
    else {
        // Save photo failed with no error
    }
})
```

Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetChangeRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PHAssetChangeRequest/creationDate) to the Apple documentation.

Don't forget to add the appropriate key/value to your info.plist to request permission to access the photo library:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Enable camera access to take photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Enable photo library access to select a photo from your library.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Enable photo library access to save images to your photo library directly from the app.</string>
```

Comment: How can get the image url @ricardopereira

Comment: @Mansuu Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37248867/3641812

Answer (score 11):

For reference, you can save videos in a similar manner:

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath, nil, nil, nil);
```

You might want to save a video to upload to Instagram, for example:

```
// Save video to camera roll; we can share to Instagram from there.
-(void)didTapShareToInstagram:(id)sender { 
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.videoPath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), (void*)CFBridgingRetain(@{@"caption" : caption}));
}

- (void)               video: (NSString *) videoPath
    didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error
                 contextInfo: (void *) contextInfoPtr {

    NSDictionary *contextInfo = CFBridgingRelease(contextInfoPtr);
    NSString *caption         = contextInfo[@"caption"];

    NSString *escapedString   = [videoPath stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]; // urlencodedString
    NSString *escapedCaption  = [caption stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]; // urlencodedString

    NSURL *instagramURL       = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@", escapedString, escapedCaption]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

Answer (score 11):

### Save the image in photo library in Swift 4

Add "Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description" in info.plist

Then use following code to save image

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image!, nil, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use  asImage() to get unique content to save to the camera roll.**

If you use asImage() you can save a variety of fun things to the camera roll with just a few lines of code!  This can be very powerful if the object has some transparency already incorporated.

asImage() works with UITextView, WKWebView, UIImageView, UIButton, UISlider, UITableView to name some objects (but they may need to be visible when you get the image (having a non zero alpha)).  I even use it to capture tiling, but that's loaded into a UIImageView already in my design.  I suspect asImage() may work with many more object types too, but I only tried the ones I mentioned.

If it's a UITextView, and you set the background color to .clear then the text gets saved with a transparent background.  If your text contains emoji or Memoji, you can now get those images into the camera roll, or into UIImageViews internal to your app.   Having Memoji/Emoji with a transparent background in your camera roll where they can be used in any variety of applications is powerful.

Other objects may have some transparency if you crop a photo image to a circle, or set the corner radius to clip off the corners.

Note in my code, pointerToTextObjectSelected is a UITextView

```
    
var pointerToTextObjectSelected = UITextView()
// above populated elsewhere
              
let thisObject = pointerToTextObjectSelected.asImage()
                
let imageData = thisObject.pngData()
                
let imageToSave = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave!, nil, nil, nil)

// You will need this extension :

extension UIView {

  // Using a function since `var image` might conflict with an existing variable
  // (like on `UIImageView`)
  func asImage() -> UIImage {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
      return renderer.image { rendererContext in
        layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
      }
    } else {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
      self.layer.render(in:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
      let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      return UIImage(cgImage: image!.cgImage!)
    }
  }
}
```