# codenameone downloading files/images visible to other apps

Tags: image, download, codenameone

I note that other apps (testing on Android) like WhatsApp, etc have folders that contains images the user has used/downloaded. These folders (like WhatsAppImages) are visible in other apps (Gallery/File Explorers, etc) so you can use those files to share, delete, etc like any other file.

In my codenameone app I download image files but they cannot be seen anywhere on the local device. I understand that for security apps run in a sandbox and this may be why.

But how do these other apps make their downloaded files visible to the general file system and other apps ?

Many Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codename One doesn't support that at this time but you can use native interfaces to add this as explained here for Android: [How to save image in android gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859584/how-to-save-image-in-android-gallery)

and here for iOS: [How can I save an image to the camera roll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131050/how-can-i-save-an-image-to-the-camera-roll)

You can also file an RFE to add this either as a cn1lib or API.